# When to choose Azure VM Scale sets and Azure Virtual Desktop Host pools

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, windows-virtual-desktop

I am basically looking a brief explanation on when to choose Azure scale sets and Azure Virtual Host pools.

Comment: Virtual host pools are specific to windows virtual desktop. If not using WVD, use VMSS.

Answer (score 0):

You create Azure VM Scale Sets when you want to build large-scale services that are highly available. Using VM scale sets would let you create and manage a group of load balanced VMs and maintain a consistent configuration across all instances.

Scale sets can automatically increase the number of VM instances as application demand increases, then reduce the number of VM instances as demand decreases. This ability helps reduce costs and efficiently create Azure resources as required matching your customer demand.

@mmking is right in that Host pools are specific to WVD. Host pools are like a collection of identical virtual machines within Windows Virtual Desktop environments.

Additional resources:

- [Virtual machine scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview)
- [WVD host pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/create-host-pools-azure-marketplace)